# Running one Autokey script from another Autokey script?

Tags: linux, autokey

Right now I've got two Autokey scripts (for modularity), one that opens a file, and one that puts text in it.

The one that opens the file has hotkey `F1` (and we'll call this script `1` for simplicity), and the one that puts text in it has hotkey `F2`. I want a new Autokey script, that when I hit `F3`, it runs both the `1` script and the `2` script.

I've tried making the `3` script just send the `F1` and `F2` keys, but the timing is all off. It would be better if I could just call `1` and `2` from `3`. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/fc7c6b90f3f28a57ad256829ef2b69e3be5148d2/lib/autokey/scripting.py#L1242

`engine.run_script("<description>")`

ought to do the trick

"Description" in this context is generally the name of the script in the side bar in the AutoKey interface. If you open up the `.json` file for the script you can see it for sure, but it will be the name displayed in the side bar unless you have duplicate names for scripts in the same folder or some other edge scenario

Answer (score 3):

AutoKey is not recursive. It does not inspect the output of an AutoKey phrase or script to look for hotkeys or trigger abbreviations which would invoke further actions. That's why your initial solution does not work.

It depends on what you're actually trying to do.

If you have multiple independently useful scripts, the best approach is the one @Icallitvera offers.

If you just want to modularize shared functionality, you can create Python modules of functions and place them in the AutoKey Modules directory. Then, you can import them into any AutoKey script which needs them.

You can find/set the Modules directory from the AutoKey Main Menu via `Settings->Configure AutoKey->Script Engine`.

At the moment, this approach is limited because scripts invoked this way do not (easily) have access to the AutoKey API, so they can't include any API calls. We plan to fix this in the next major release, AutoKey 0.96. If you really need to do that now, ask on our [support list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/autokey-users) or on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/autokey/autokey).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into that same problem and the only way I found to work around that restriction is by using the `exec()` function. Since the scripts with functions to share were already in the AutoKey user folder I used that. So in order to load shared functions of my user module "mygame" into the autokey script I used:

```
exec(open(engine.configManager.userCodeDir + "/" + "mygame.py").read())
```

To avoid name collisions when "importing" more than one script and a more module-like feeling I put the functions in classes and instantiate with a variable that is named like the module.

So in the end it looks like this:

mygame.py:

```
import time

class MyGame:
    def GameReload(self):
        self.GameExitNoSave()
        time.sleep(0.3)
        self.GameLoadCurrent()

    def GameExitNoSave(self):
        keyboard.send_key('d')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.send_key('<up>')
        time.sleep(0.05)
        keyboard.send_key('<enter>')

    def GameLoadCurrent(self):
        keyboard.send_key('<down>')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.send_key('<down>')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        keyboard.send_key('<enter>')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.send_key('<enter>')
        
mygame = MyGame()
```

User script in AutoKey:

```
exec(open(engine.configManager.userCodeDir + "/" + "mygame.py").read())

mygame.GameReload():
```